# jQuery trigger click function via done not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a button, click it, it will open a modal and fetch data via `ajax`.

Besides, there are some tabs on the modal. When the user click the button, it will open the modal and click the tab by default.

It's hard to describe, so I've written the following code.

```
$('#open_mission_btn > .the_btn').click().done(function(){
    $('#my_books_bookmark').click();
});
```

But it seems not work.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: `click()` is not an async function so the use of `done()` is redundant

Comment: what error do you have in console ?

Comment: why not make `.click(function)` ?

Comment: If you are try to trigger a click on an element in the modal window, you need to add the modal window id before the element id - something like this; `$('#my_modal #my_books_bookmark').click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger your click event in the success/done function of your ajax call

```
success:function(data) {
$('#my_books_bookmark').click();
}
```

to set the default tab to be open if you are using bootstrap you can do the following:

```
$('#myTabs a[href="#default"]').tab('show');
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Comment: Thanks for reading my ambiguous question, I really don't know how to describe that question.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the element #my_books_bookmark is loading from Ajax. When you are clicking the button, modal will pop up and ajax call fetch data. When you trigger `$('#my_books_bookmark').click();`  this button may not be loaded in DOM and click function won't trigger. Add it inside success / done of Ajax call ( which will make sure that button is loaded on the DOM )

```
success:function(data) {
$('#my_books_bookmark').click();
}
```